# Turtle racing game using classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm making a racing game using 3 different colored turtles. I'm not sure why the turtle window won't pop up. The main method is supposed to create a `turtleRace()` object that creates 4 turtles. It then calls the `drawTrack()` method that uses the `graphTurtle` to draw the race numbers.

```
import turtle
import random
import time

class turtleRace():
    def __init__(self):
        self.graphTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.redTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.greenTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.blueTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.drawTrack()
        self.drawTurtle()
        
    def drawTrack(self): #draws the racing track for the turtles
        self.graphTurtle.speed(1000)
        self.graphTurtle.penup()
        self.graphTurtle.goto(-300,200)

        for i in range(0,20):
            self.graphTurtle.write(i)
            self.graphTurtle.right(90)
            self.graphTurtle.forward(5)
            self.graphTurtle.pendown()
            self.graphTurtle.forward(400)
            self.graphTurtle.penup()
            self.graphTurtle.left(180)
            self.graphTurtle.forward(405)
            self.graphTurtle.right(90)
            self.graphTurtle.forward(30)
        
    def drawTurtle(self): #draws 3 turtles and sets them to the beginning or race
        self.redTurtle.color('red')
        self.redTurtle.shape('turtle')
        self.redTurtle.penup()
        self.greenTurtle.color('red')
        self.greenTurtle.shape('turtle')
        self.greenTurtle.penup()
        self.blueTurtle.color('red')
        self.blueTurtle.shape('turtle')
        self.blueTurtle.penup()
            
        self.redTurtle.goto(-300,100)
        self.greenTurtle.goto(-300,0)
        self.blueTurtle.goto(-300,-100)
        self.redTurtle.pendown()
        self.greenTurtle.pendown()
        self.blueTurtle.pendown()
        
    def raceTurtles(self): #will push the turtles forward a random amount
        pass

def main():
    tRace = turtleRace()
    tRace.raceTurtles()
    return

main()
```

Comment: What happened when you tried running the program from the command line? Do you see any error messages?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. It pops open the turtle window, but no racing track is drawn, The error says "'turtleRace' object has no attribute 'drawTrack'"

Comment: You should *explain* that *in your post*, and *show* the [*complete*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) error message, formatted as code. Please read [ask].

Comment: You should also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and thus try to fix the problem yourself. If you can't fix it, you should at least be able to narrow down where it's happening, and produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So I learned about Indents and realized that I had tabs and spaces mixed in. I solved that and it ended up fixing the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

On line 45 you have variable `BlueTurtle`, which is not declared, you need to change it to `blueTurtle`.

[image]

Comment: I changed it, but it didn't seem to be the main problem. The turtle window still won't pop up.

Comment: Hm, strange, everything seems ok for me. I've attached image to my answer. Which python version are you using? @DaSeksyDolan

Comment: I'm using python 3.9.5